# 5.1 sound in Unity3d 3.5

Tags: unity, audio

I'm trying to implement 5.1 surround sound in my game. I've set Unity's AudioManager to a default of 5.1 surround and loaded in a 6 channel audio clip that should play a sound in each of the different audio spots.

However, when I go to run my game, all I get is flat sound coming out of my front two speakers. Even then, these don't play the sound they should (front speaker should play "front speaker" right should play "right speaker" and so). Both speakers just end up playing the entire sound file.

I've tried looking to see if there is a parameter that I have missed, but information on how to set up 5.1 sound in Unity is lacking (or my google skills aren't that good) and I can't get it to work as intended. Could someone please either tell me what I'm missing, or point me in the right direction?

My audio source is situated at point (0, 0, 0) with my camera also being in the same point. I've moved about the scene but the same thing happens as I've already described.

Comment: What are the import settings for the AudioClip? And is your AudioListener attached to your character controller?